# How to use a global variable in an array index using Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to access an object in an array using a global variable. However, it seems that Handlebars does not allow you to do that. Is there a way around this problem?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Handlebars.js example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder">This will get replaced by handlebars.js</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr><th>testing</th><td> <input type="text"><td></tr>
        {{!names[index] is not working}}
------>     {{#each names.[index]}}
        <tr><th> {{this}}</th><td><input type="text"><td></tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source = document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var index=0;
        var data = {
            names: [
            { name: "foo",id:'id',type:"type"},
            { name: "bar",id:'id' },
            { name: "baz",id:'id' }
            ]};
              document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = template(data);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know in this example that I don't need to use a global variable, but with the code that I am using I need to. Please no JQuery, as I can't use it.

**EDIT**:This is what I am trying to do in the each helper. I am going through each of the attributes of one object. In order to do so, I must select an object at a particular index like names.[0] for example.

Comment: is `{{!names[index] is not working}}` valid handlebars syntax?

Comment: yes. It is comments in handlebars. Even with that line removed it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Handlebars can't access a global variable from inside the template. (By the way, `index` isn't global). You'll probably have to pass `index` in the context given to `template()`
2. `{{#each names.[index]}}` doesn't resolve to iterate `(names[index])` but `(names['index']`, which is not what you want. (`{{#each names.[0]}}` works since `0` isn't converted to a string)
3. The solution:

   - My favorite ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/14ezuk3a/2/)), give the wanted element of `names` directly in the context

     ```
     template({selected:data.names[index]});
     ```
   - Use a custom helper ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/14ezuk3a/3/))

     ```
     Handlebars.registerHelper('at', function(context, index, options) {
       if( options.fn ) return options.fn(context[index]);
       return context[index];
     });
     ```

     and

     ```
     {{#at names index}}{{#each .}}
         <tr><th>{{@key}}</th><td><input type="text" value="{{.}}"><td></tr>
     {{/each}}{{/at}}
     ```

Finally, you can also ask for a better solution or a new feature for this issue [on github.com/wycats/handlebars.js](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues)

Comment: what does selected mean in this line: template({selected:data.names[index]});

Comment: It's the name in the template of the element you want to iterate over: `{{#each selected}} ... {{/each}}`. You can see it in the example. Of course you can change `selected` to whatever variable name you think best-suited.